# Does formatting belong in the view or in the services layer?

Tags: design, unit-testing, n-tier

Should you format numbers in the view or in the services layer?

If you are going to round a number to 2 decimal places. Does it make sense if that number is rounded in the view or in the services layer? What about if that number is a nullable type like in C#? I don't want to write `if(number.HasValue) { number.ToString() }`

It is definitely more testable if this is done in the services layer for more complex formatting.

Comment: Internationalization is a larger problem than just deciding which layer to put it in.  I suggest that you do a bit of research in your chosen technologies to find commonly-used strategies, and then come back here with a more focused question.

Comment: Although having an automated unit test for a GUI can be difficult to the point of don't bother, it shouldn't be that bad if all you're testing is a change in format to a given input. Seems doable.

Answer (score 5):

If you put it in the service layer, then EVERYTHING that uses that service will get the formatted result. This may or may not be a problem, depending on who will use the service and whether or not some users need a different format.

If you put it in the view layer, then the view is doing all of the formatting work. Maybe you're worried this could cause performance issues if you have to format something *n* times on a page/UI component, instead of once in the service layer. I wouldn't worry about number formatting causing a major performance hit, but at the very least, it means that each UI component might need to have its own internal formatter if it expects to receive unformatted data.

ALSO...

You could add a formatting option to the service request, so that clients that want a pre-formatted result will get one (with one of a few pre-defined formatting choices), and others will get the more "raw" data, to format as they see fit. This is something I've seen a few times, though it is usually in context of formatting of an entire *dataset*: tsv vs. JSON vs. XML vs. binary... but it can also be done for individual data fields where formatting is important.